# How to use empty and selected in same dropdown box in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I'm editing a dropdown box. i need to use empty and selected in same dropdown.
here is my code

```
$this->Form->input('per', array('id'=>'per','class'=>'inputs con_field','label'=>'per :', 'type'=>'select','options'=>$per_values,'selected'=>$labrcfps['Labourcfps']['per'],'empty'=>'- - Select --'));
```

If i use empty it automatically takes the empty as selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new in cakephp but i do this with array and parameter defaults :)

like that:

```
    $options = array(
    'x' => 'Select',
    1 => 'Something',
    2 => 'Car',
    3 => 'Train'
    );
    echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'options' => $options,
    'default' => 'x'
    ));
```

Maybe that will be working fine :)
Variable $options is just your options after that you can validate if name of that field has value integer or 'x'. If 'x' then deny rest of logical code

Comment: I'm creating the option dynamically.

Comment: I know, just put your options to variable than add position with ('x'=> 'Select') after that echo's input field like as i wrote